# Uninstalling atom from mac

Tags: macos, atom-editor, uninstallation

I have followed [this page](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-atom-for-mac/9084) to remove recommended directory. here is what i have removed so far

```
rm -rf ~/.atom
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/atom
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/apm
rm -rf /Applications/Atom.app
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.github.atom.plist
rm -rf ~/"Library/Application Support/com.github.atom.ShipIt"
rm -rf ~/"Library/Application Support/Atom"
rm -rf ~/"Library/Saved Application State/com.github.atom.savedState"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.github.atom
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.github.atom.Shipit
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/Atom
```

Yet, when i open the context menu on files to see *open with* option, I find **Atom** there. If i choose **Atom** to open given file, it opens Atom application.

So can someone tell how to uninstall atom properly?

I also notice that some of my files like `.js` are associated with atom editor i.e., they are displaying atom icon.

Comment: Try this command `rm -rf ~/Applications/Atom.app` (Note: The trailing `~`)

Comment: tried that, it still exist in context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is a bit late to reply at this post, but I ran into the same issue and found that Atom.app was still in some directory when I downloaded it and unzipped. I didn't drag it to Application folder at the beggining, but MacOs still identifies every .app file as an application, so I had to look for it and delete its folder:

```
find ~/ -iname Atom.app -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!  I also tried all the command line removals, but in the end, the atom.app file was in the Downloads folder for me.  Once I deleted the .app file from the Downloads folder, I was finally free.

Comment: Even I faced the same thing After removing it from the Downloads folder it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not add an "Open with" option to the Finder context menu, you must have used a third-party tool or created it yourself (e.g. using an [Automator workflow](https://gist.github.com/idleberg/874790e8e3c8b1419e4439d0a48d2aa5)).

Take a look for that entry in `~/Library/Services`.

Comment: There is nothing in `~/Library/Services` folder.